# How to split a string at every Nth occurrence of a character in Java

Tags: java

I'm trying to split a String at every Nth occurence, but missing the last values.Here is what is expected.

Input : `String str = "234-236-456-567-678-675-453-564";`

Output :

```
234-236-456  
567-678-675  
453-564
```

Here `N=3`, where the `str` should be split at every 3rd occurence of `-`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe one of the worst way without using function available in java , but good like exercise :

```
public static void main(String[] args){
        String s = "234-236-456-567-678-675-453-564";
        int nth =0;
        int cont =0;
        int i=0;
        for(;i<s.length();i++){
            if(s.charAt(i)=='-')
                nth++;
            if(nth == 3 || i==s.length()-1){
                if(i==s.length()-1) //with this if you preveent to cut the last number
                System.out.println(s.substring(cont,i+1));
                else
                    System.out.println(s.substring(cont,i));
                nth=0;
                cont =i+1;


            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: replace `for(;i<s.length();i++){` with `for( int i = 0, cont = 0, nth = 0; i < s.length(); i++ ){` and remove the int-variables declared above the for statement. That way the variables are only available in the for-scope

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
String str = "234-236-456-567-678-675-453-564";
String[] f = str.split("(?<=\\G.*-.*-.*)-");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(f));
```

result:

```
[234-236-456, 567-678-675, 453-564]
```

Comment: Maybe you could explain the `\\G` in the lookbehind.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following with Java 8:

```
String str = "234-236-456-567-678-675-453-564";
Lists.partition(Lists.newArrayList(str.split("-")), 3)
    .stream().map(strings -> strings.stream().collect(Collectors.joining("-")))
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Output:

```
234-236-456
567-678-675
453-564
```