# Split string and repeat xml tag based on nth occurance of special character

Tags: groovy

I want to split the xml tags based on the nth occurance of special character coming in input tags using groovy

I have a xml input with many tags that hold huge data. I want to split the xml tags based on the nth occurance of special character coming in the input tags using groovy.

[How to split a string at every Nth occurrence of a character in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45322905/how-to-split-a-string-at-every-nth-occurrence-of-a-character-in-java)  -- this logic works for me but for one xml tag. I have multiple xml tags and want to split all the tags based on say 4th occurance of delimiter '/'.

Can I get some directions to achieve this? Thanks.

Example input xml:

```
<Row>
<EntityID>9035158701/9035158702/9035158703/9035158704/9035158705/9035158706/9035158707/9035158708/9035158709/9035158710</EntityID>
<RefID>7U2HYUTP/5Z1IWGUS/7AK9MDDJ/6RP9DXAW/29FBRBEL/5YKDCO3B/75MUQU7S/57QCGOQE/2EUX64ON/2VTJPVUV</RefID>
</Row>
```

Expected Output:

```
<Root>
<Row>
<EntityID>9035158701/9035158702/9035158703/9035158704</EntityID>
<RefID>7U2HYUTP/5Z1IWGUS/7AK9MDDJ/6RP9DXAW</RefID>
</Row>
<Row>
<EntityID>9035158705/9035158706/9035158707/9035158708</EntityID>
<RefID>29FBRBEL/5YKDCO3B/75MUQU7S/57QCGOQE</RefID>
</Row>
<Row>
<EntityID>9035158709/9035158710</EntityID>
<RefID>2EUX64ON/2VTJPVUV</RefID>
</Row>
</Root>
```

```
import com.sap.gateway.ip.core.customdev.util.Message;
import java.util.HashMap;
import groovy.xml.*;

def Message processData(Message message) {

        def body = message.getBody(java.io.Reader)
        assert body != null
        def input = new XmlSlurper().parse(body);
        def entityid = input.EntityID.text();
        def refid = input.RefID.text();
        int nth=0;
        int cont=0;
        
        def writer = new StringWriter()
        for(int i=0;i<entityid.length();i++){
            if(entityid.charAt(i)=='/')
                nth++;
                
            if(nth == 4 || i==entityid.length()-1){
                new MarkupBuilder(writer).Row{
                
                if(i==entityid.length()-1) //with this if you preveent to cut the last number
                EntityID (entityid.substring(cont,i+1))
                
                else
                    EntityID (entityid.substring(cont,i+1))
                nth=0;
                cont =i+1;
            }
        }
        }
       def output = writer.toString()
       message.setBody(output)      
       return message;
}
```

Comment: Can you paste the code you currently have into the question?

Comment: I have added the code Tim.

Comment: Hi tim_yates, I had to get back on this again. I tested the code locally and it worked good. But in runtime, I am getting this error ---->No signature of method: [Ljava.lang.String;.collate() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.Integer) values: [4]
Possible solutions: collect(), collect(groovy.lang.Closure), toList(), collect(java.util.Collection, groovy.lang.Closure), take(int), count(java.lang.Object) ----- Appreciate any pointers on this error. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `split` to separate the string by a character, then use `collate` to batch them together into groups, then `join` the elements of each group, and `transpose` the Entity and Ref ids together for each row:

```
def processData(String input) {
    def parsed = new XmlParser().parseText(input)
    
    def eids = parsed.EntityID.text().split("/").collate(4)*.join("/")
    def rids = parsed.RefID.text().split("/").collate(4)*.join("/")
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter()
    new MarkupBuilder(writer).Root {
        [eids, rids].transpose().each { eid, rid ->
            Row {
                EntityID(eid)
                RefID(rid)
            }
        }
    }
    writer.toString()
}
```

That takes a String, and returns a String, so you'll need to integrate it with the Message class (as you have above)

```
def input = '''<Row>
<EntityID>9035158701/9035158702/9035158703/9035158704/9035158705/9035158706/9035158707/9035158708/9035158709/9035158710</EntityID>
<RefID>7U2HYUTP/5Z1IWGUS/7AK9MDDJ/6RP9DXAW/29FBRBEL/5YKDCO3B/75MUQU7S/57QCGOQE/2EUX64ON/2VTJPVUV</RefID>
</Row>'''

processData(input)
```

returns

```
<Root>
  <Row>
    <EntityID>9035158701/9035158702/9035158703/9035158704</EntityID>
    <RefID>7U2HYUTP/5Z1IWGUS/7AK9MDDJ/6RP9DXAW</RefID>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <EntityID>9035158705/9035158706/9035158707/9035158708</EntityID>
    <RefID>29FBRBEL/5YKDCO3B/75MUQU7S/57QCGOQE</RefID>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <EntityID>9035158709/9035158710</EntityID>
    <RefID>2EUX64ON/2VTJPVUV</RefID>
  </Row>
</Root>
```